# How to show expanded-item slot with costom body slot?

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

How to show expanded-item slot with costom body slot ?

On button click, I push to expanded array. Nothing happens.

How to fix it ?

https://codesandbox.io/s/empty-fast-kbzzh

Comment: Good example [enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58723645/v-data-table-controlling-expanded-items-via-v-slotbody?rq=1)

Answer (score 0):

Due to Vue's limited reactivity in Arrays and Objects you have to reassign those in order to work.

Try this:

```
methods: {
  expandItem(item) {
    this.expanded = [...this.expanded, item];
  }
},
```